# VB exe not finding configuration file calling from R System/System2

Tags: r, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint

I have an .exe `MapaReporting.exe` which has a .config file `MapaReporting.exe.config` where some of the static parameters (e.g. URL) are specified. 
If I run the .exe from the CMD prompt it does what is supposed to be doing (uploading a file to SharePoint).

[image]

This means to me that both the .exe and the .config are doing their job.

I then try to call the same job with R using the relevant `system` instruction. The essence of what I do is provided by this short script (the actual thing involves a proper function but the lines below are what matter):

```
currentDir <- getwd()
setwd("//UKLDNNAS902/RESTRICTED/Fund of Funds/Team/Matteo/R/SPUploader")
exeFile <- "MapaReporting.exe"
exeString <- "PhysicalLocation-C:\\DELETEME.xlsx filename-THISISATEST.xlsx FolderName-SFR ReportType-SFR ReportDate-12/12/2016 Fund-NAF PortfolioManager-A566848"
system(paste(exeFile, exeString))
setwd(currentDir)
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Site Url is missing in configuration file.   at MapaReporting.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Which points to the fact that while using CMD the .exe finds the relevant .config, when I try the same with R it throws that error. I tried to encapsulate the system call in the relevant folder as you can see and I also tried the `system2` function.
All without success. Any help is more than welcome! Thanks.

UPDATE: Having modified the script in order to point to a local folder and having added the `wait = T` option to the `system` statement as per Greg suggestions below nothing changed.

Using the Process Monitor utility these are the list of failures:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things you might try:

1. Change the system command to "wait" like this: `system(paste(exeFile, exeString), wait=T)`
2. It looks like you are running your executable from a network share (//UKLDNNAS902).  Does it work if you copy the files to a local local drive, and run it from there?  This could indicate a problem with Share or File Permissions.
3. Download and run [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), run your system command again, and look for any events in the Procmon Console related to your .config file. This can give you hints as to what is going wrong when your program tries to read this file (e.g. trying to read from the wrong location, permission problems, etc.).  If the .config file does not ever appear in the ProcMon console, look for any failed events indicating that a library (or registry entry) needed for reading the .config file failed to load.

**Update:**  I was able to reproduce your problem by re-creating a .Net/C# command line app that reads from a .config file.  I was able to fix the problem by changing the command line like this:

```
exeFile <- "cmd.exe /C MapaReporting.exe"
```

For reference, here is the entire script I used:

```
currentDir <- getwd()
setwd("C:/SPUploader")
exeFile <- "cmd.exe /C ConsoleApplicationTest.exe"
exeString <- "PhysicalLocation-C:\\DELETEME.xlsx filename-THISISATEST.xlsx FolderName-SFR ReportType-SFR ReportDate-12/12/2016 Fund-NAF PortfolioManager-A566848"
system(paste(exeFile, exeString))
setwd(currentDir)
```

Note that I ran this in RStudio as Administrator.

Let me know if this works for you...

Comment: Thanks Greg,
I tried the following merging 1 and 2 above:

`exeFile <- "c:/SPUploader/MapaReporting.exe"` `exeString` same as before and then `system(paste(exeFile, exeString, wait=T))` 

but I have the same error as mentioned above.
I will try with 3 now trying to understand what is wrong. What I don't understand is that the whole thing seems to find the relevant .dll `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll` all right. I am tempted to discard any issue with permissioning.

Comment: Updated with the output from ProcMon utility. Please let me know if you need something else to identify any issue.

Comment: Still no joy I am afraid but I gave it only a quick try. Let me have a better look tomorrow.

Comment: Please make sure MapaReporting.exe.config file file is in same directory as MapaReporting.exe file.

Comment: Yep, that's been always that way. Alongside the .dll files.

Comment: In that case, please show me a screenshot of ProcMon which shows the loading of the MapaReporting.exe.config file as well as the other Dlls.

Comment: Good news: I finally managed to get your solution based on `cmd.exe /C [filename].exe` to work. That was the problem. I am very sorry for messing up the first time I tried (I honestly do not know what I did wrong but nevermind). Thank you once more!